# is there a mongo php extension for visual studio 2010

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010, mongodb

do they make mongodb php extension for visual studio 2010 (on a win7 32bt operating system) and php version 5.2?

i've seen sites that have the dll for download.  (sites listed at the end of this text).

but, looking a the different dlls, i only see them for vc9 and vc11.   does that mean that isn't  mongo/php extension for my version of visual studio?

any info would be greatly appreciated.  thank you.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads

https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to download and use a precompiled PHP extension for MongoDB, the important details to match up are: your version of PHP, what compiler was used, and whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit.

You can get this information from the `phpinfo()` details or by running `php -i` from a commmand line.

Look for a "PHP Extension Build" line similar to:

```
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,TS,VC9
```

You should then [download the latest MongoDB driver DLL zip](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html) and find the appropriate DLL to install (matching PHP version, TS vs NTS, and VC version).

For example, with the above output from my 64-bit PHP 5.4 install I would use the `php_mongo-1.4.x-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll`.

If your PHP extensions require something other than VC9 or VC11 (which is what the current versions are built with) you can try older driver versions, or ideally update your PHP to a newer version.